# Maximal subcategory inside a multicategory

Tags: category-theory, terminology, operads

Let $\mathcal M$ be a multicategory. Let $C(\mathcal M)$ be a category consisting of all objects and all unary multimorphisms of $\mathcal M$.

Is there a standard name for $C(\mathcal M)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called the "underlying category of $\mathcal{M}$" in Lurie's [*Higher Algebra*](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf) (Remark 2.1.1.2). I don't know how standard this terminology is, it probably depends on who you ask; I've seen it used at least another time (I don't remember where exactly though).

(Personally I would probably just call that "the category of unary operations".)